# Select value during onblur event when using typeahead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a simple **typeahead** for a list of currencies. When I start typing and I select the desired value (or hit TAB on that), the desired value is selected - until this point everything works as desired.

However, **if I type the entire word and click outside the input instead of selecting the value** (onblur event), then even if the value inside my input matches the filter value, the *selected* scope variable doesn't update, so my input is invalid. What I'm trying to do is to overwrite the selected value during onblur event.

Example: If I type **EUR** without hitting TAB or selecting the **EUR** value from the typeahead dropdown and then click outside the input, the **EUR** text stays inside the input, but selected value is **undefined**. I want the selected value to hold EUR instead of undefined. I used **$viewValue** to send the input value during onblur event.

The HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead-editable="false" typeahead="currency for currency in currencies | filter:$viewValue" ng-blur="selectCurrency($viewValue)" />
<div>Selected: {{selected}}</div>
```

The JavaScipt:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.selected = '';
    $scope.currencies = ['EUR', 'GBP', 'USD'];
    $scope.selectCurrency = function(test) {
        console.log(test); //outputs undefined instead of EUR
        //if (checkIfCurrencyExists(test, $scope.currencies)) { - will do the checks later
        $scope.selected = test;
        //}
    };
});
```

In the JsFiddle below you can see the same scenario, except it has US states instead of currencies. Try to type in **Alabama** then **left click outside the input** (don't TAB and don't select the state), you'll see that the selected scope variable stays empty

JsFiddle link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjPWe/192/).

Comment: Do you want to select the first value from the result on blur?

Comment: Thanks for replying, Shashank. Not necessarily, I want to get the value from the input and process it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer myself at the time, but forgot to answer my question here.

Added this to the directive:

```
data-ng-blur="blur($event)"
```

And this is the function:

```
$scope.blur = function(e) {
            var inputCurrency = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
            angular.forEach($scope.currencies, function(currency) {
                if (currency === inputCurrency) {
                    $scope.field = currency;
                }
            });
        };
```

Comment: Hi, I used your code but it is not working. Is this really working for you?

Comment: I tried similar and it does working unlike comment from KCN. I think it's not very simple for everybody to understand maybe because people miss example with link that you provided in other post, but it should be up-voted more times.

Answer (score 2):

Found another solution - setting both typeahead-select-on-exact and typeahead-select-on-blur attributes to true:

```html
   <input typeahead-select-on-exact="true" typeahead-select-on-blur="true" uib-typeahead=...
```

Typeahead-select-on-exact makes the exactly matching item automatically highlighted in the list, and typeahead-select-on-blur makes the higlighted item selected on blur.

Comment: Warm congrats... +5 claps

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the first result from the typeahead list on blur, then you can set `typeahead-select-on-blur="true"` in your `input` field as given in the [doc](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead).

> `typeahead-select-on-blur` (**Default: false**) - On blur, select the
>   currently highlighted match.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to do what I want, I have modified the **JsFiddle** below to better illustrate the scenario. This example has US states instead of currencies. Try to type in **Alabama** then **mouse click outside the input** (don't TAB and don't select the state), you'll see that the **selected** scope variable stays empty: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjPWe/192/)

Comment: Does this answer work for when I click out of the input?

Answer (score 1):

I spend some time searching for similar question and made a lot of testing untill I got it working. I can see that in answers there is a solution but I try to summarize it so it could be a bit more clear.

In typeahead part include:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead-editable="false" typeahead="currency for currency in currencies | filter:$viewValue" ng-blur="checkSelectedValue()" typeahead-select-on-blur="true" />
```

First part includes validation function of your scope value (you don't need to pass the value as it's the $scope.selected and you can use it in your controller): ng-blur="checkSelectedValue()".
Thus include in your controller:

```
$scope.checkSelectedValue = function() {
  if (code that check if $scope.selected in range of allowed values) { 
    $scope.inputValid=true; //you can use this scope or write code that run when selected a correct value
  } else {
    $scope.inputValid=false; 
}};
```

Second part: typeahead-select-on-blur="true"// it's necessary since it first will make $scope.selected=selected value from dropdown (complete word) but also a bit weird, but important to know that after typeahead will selected your value it will run ng-blur= "checkSelectedValue()" directive in the end so there it will always check for validation and will set your $scope.inputValid=true or false depending on $scope.selected value.